Excel VBA Guardar el segundo libro nuevo
Tengo 2 Libros abiertos, necesito que el 2do libro abierto se guarde con un nombre específico pero que siga abierto y si ya existe el archivo con el mismo nombre, solo lo reemplace , al ejecutar la macro me sale mensaje de error sin poder corregirlo
Aqui la macro:
Sub GrabarLibro()

    Dim milibro As Workbook
    
    For Each milibro In Workbooks

        If milibro.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        
           milibro.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\LIVIA\Downloads\Libro1.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
           
        End If
    
    Next milibro
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
        
End Sub


No tengo claro lo que intentas hacer pero esto podría ayudarte:
Sub GrabarLibro()

    Dim milibro As Workbook
    Dim LibroActual As Workbook
    Dim Ruta As String
    
    Ruta = ThisWorkbook.Path    'Ruta donde se encuentra el segundo libro.
    
    Set LibroActual = ThisWorkbook  'Libro actual desde donde ejectuas la macro
    Set milibro = Workbooks.Open(Ruta & "\Libro1.xlsx") 'Segundo libro. Primero debes abrir el segundo libro y tenerlo referenciado para poder modificarlo o hacer lo que tengas que hacer con el
    
    For Each milibro In Workbooks   'Este bucle For Each podrías eliminarlo

        If milibro.Name <> LibroActual.Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'Con esto evitas que pregunte si deseas sobreescribir el archivo si ya existe.
            milibro.SaveAs Filename:=Ruta & "\Libro1.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    
    Next milibro
    
    LibroActual.Save
        
End Sub


Revisar [answer]. saludos.

Funcionó sin agregar el SET ni los otros Dim, ya que al usarlo me sale Error de Compilación o Error de sintaxis (adjunto imagen):

Con este código funcionó.
Sub GrabarLibro()

  Dim milibro As Workbook
    
  For Each milibro In Workbooks
   
      If milibro.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
         milibro.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\LIVIA\Downloads\Libro2.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         milibro.Close
       End If

    Next milibro
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
End Sub


No olvides aceptar tu respuesta si es que fue lo que respondió a tu pregunta.
